# What's the explicit description of the atlas of quotient stack?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $U\to[U/G]$ be a quotient stack. How does one associate a $G$-torsor $P\to S$ and a equivariant map $P\to U$ to each $S\to U$?

Comment: Your question is rather different from what you ask in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $S = U$ this is the trivial torsor $P = U \times G$, and for any other $S \to U$, this is its pullback, which is also the trivial torsor $P = S \times G$.